# Is relying on an exception for a failed attempt an acceptable way to return a bool?

Tags: c#, refactoring, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-1.0

This query:

```
string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
```

...which I'm using as the guts of an "isValidTable(string tableName)" method, throws an exception if the tableName does not exist (specifically, "The specified table does not exist").

That being the case (it doesn't play nice, it throws up its hands if it doesn't recognize the table name) makes me wonder if this code:

```
public bool isValidTable(string tableName)
{
    bool validTable = false;
    string tblQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
        object objcnt = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if ((objcnt != null) && (objcnt != DBNull.Value)) 
        {
            validTable = Int32.Parse(objcnt.ToString()) > 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL returned from isValidTable(). Remove this line."); //<- I never see this; if this is the case, an exception has been thrown
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return validTable;
}
```

...could/should be simplified to:

```
public bool isValidTable(string tableName)
{
    string tblQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

?

### UPDATE

jp2code opined: "select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '{0}')) then 1 else 0 end"

Is there similar code for checking if a column exists? Currently my isValidTable() and isValidColumn() queries are similar:

```
string tableQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
string columnQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT({0}) FROM {1}", columnName, tableName);
```

...but if I were able to use this for isValidTable():

```
string.Format("select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '{0}')) then 1 else 0 end",
tableName);
```

...is there also an extension of this that I could use for checking for valid columns? Something like:

```
string.Format("select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '{0}' and column_name = '{1}')) then 1 else 0 end",
tableName, columnName);
```

???

### UPDATE 2

I realize that the suggested sql is "more better" than "my way," but for whatever reason, when I use "the preferred method," needed data tables are not recognized as existing (even though, of course, they do exist). Either the ancient version of software I'm using doesn't accept nested selects/sub-selects, or...???

At any rate, the comments tells the story:

```
string tblQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
// This is doubtless "more better," but when I use it, I get "No current work; no inventory file"
//string tblQuery = string.Format("select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '{0}')) then 1 else 0 end", tableName);
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to do that, what DBMS?

Comment: sql server ce, version prehistoric

Comment: Ugh - I wish there were one, unified way to ask any DB "Yo, does this table exist?" - from my hazy memory, there was a method per DB platform to do this...(with some overlap)

Comment: sqlce definitely doesn't support nested select statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use exceptions for things that are exceptional (out of the norm), not being able to find a table is considered normal execution for that method, thus should not rely on exceptions to occur.

Things that are out of the norm for your example would be having a connection timeout, which is not standard operation for your method.

Instead, you should query the `sys.tables` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` tables to see whether your table exists.

Comment: I'm almost positive I tried that, but I can't find record of it. It seems to me my version was too old to use that. I know that I tried that or something similar, anyway, and had to resort to this other way.

Comment: I've been trying so many things over the last few days that I don't recall why I had commented that code out, but now I have reinstated:
string columnQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName";
-and:
string tableQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName";
...and it is working fine now, so...? Anyway, I gave you the green check for that reminder.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm facing the same problem i prefer looking up in a System table, as Matthew pointed out, to check  if a Table does exist or not 
and if the database I'm using doesn't give me the possibility to do that, I would simulate it by creating a table that keeps track of exist  Tables. query that table instead of wrapping the code in a by try catch block. not an elegant solution but in my modest point of view much cleaner

Comment: I posted a code example with some SQL that might get you where you need to be (might not, also).

Answer (score 1):

If you continue using this, at least specify an `SqlCeException` that you catch and disregard, that way you don't unknowingly disregard other errors that might be happening.

As for checking if a table exists or not, see this popular post:

[Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/167576/153923)

Really, if your code works, you should not have any exceptions. So after debugging and your code is ready for release, it should look more like this:

```
public bool isValidTable(string tableName)
{
  bool validTable = false;
  string tblQuery =
    string.Format("select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '{0}')) then 1 else 0 end",
    tableName);
  SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
  try
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    object objcnt = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if ((objcnt != null) && (objcnt != DBNull.Value)) 
    {
      validTable = Int32.Parse(objcnt.ToString()) > 0;
    } 
  }
  finally
  {
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  return validTable;
}
```

That particular SQL query uses a solution from this SO question:

[Check if a SQL table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464474/153923)

**Update:** How about this [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Check routine:

```
public bool isValidTable(string tableName)
{
  bool validTable = false;
  string tblQuery =
    string.Format("select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='{0}'",
    tableName);
  SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
  try
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    // I don't know if this works because I don't have .NET 1.1
    SqlCeDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    validTable = r.Read();
  }
  finally
  {
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  return validTable;
}
```

The [documentation on MSDN about DataReader 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.read%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says (in the remarks) *The default position of the SqlCeDataReader is prior to the first record. To begin accessing any data, you must call Read.* So, it should start at Index = -1 and require a Read call to make the first step into the data.

Comment: I think sub-selects are unavailable in my archaic setup (.NET 1.1, &c)

Comment: But assuming I *could* use this SQL, ... (please see  my update)

Comment: On an existing table in our SQL 2000 Server, I can enter this command and it displays a 1 Row Table with columns **TABLE_CATALOG**, **TABLE_SCHEMA**, **TABLE_NAME**, and **TABLE_TYPE**: SQL=`select * from information_schema.tables where table_name ='test_result'`

Comment: I've updated the answer with the SqlCeDataReader. It might finally give you the answer you need.

Comment: I'm relatively certain it's something bizarre in this codebase that's causing the problem, but when I replaced my existing isValidTable() code with that, the app won't even start - it just hourglasses until the cows come home.