# SQL Check if table Exists in C#, if not create

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, information-schema

I think I've seen almost every page relating to this question, most likely answer was
[Check if a SQL table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464474/check-if-a-sql-table-exists/464506#464506)
but didn't really understand it. This is what I got:

```
    private void select_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        SqlConnection SC = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ruudpc;Initial Catalog=leden;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand DateCheck = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + theDate + "'");
    }
```

Now I want a return value from DateCheck.ExecuteScalar(); that can tell me if it exists or not, probably dead simple.

**EDIT**

Regardless for the sql injection part, and that for some this question is helpful, it is generally bad practice to create tables on the fly, I recommend you reconsider your ERD. Just saying.

Comment: Don't concatenate sql for this.  Use parameterized sql to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using IF EXISTS  T-SQL

```
private void select_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

    // Enclose the connection inside a using statement to close and dispose
    // when you don't need anymore the connection (to free local and server resources)
    using(SqlConnection SC = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ruudpc;Initial Catalog=leden;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        // Sql command with parameter 
        string cmdText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                           WHERE TABLE_NAME=@name) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
        SC.Open();
        SqlCommand DateCheck = new SqlCommand(cmdText, SC);

        // Add the parameter value to the command parameters collection
        DateCheck.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = theDate

        // IF EXISTS returns the SELECT 1 if the table exists or SELECT 0 if not
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(DateCheck.ExecuteScalar());
        if (x == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Table exists for date " + theDate);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Table doesn't exist for date " + theDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you write the code can lead to sql injection attack.Parameterized SQL statements are an easy way to avoid SQL injection attacks and also a good codding practise

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkTableExist
@theDate  varchar(10)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME=@theDate) SELECT 1     ELSE SELECT 0
```

C# code

```
  try
  {     
     string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");    
     sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("checkTableExist", sqlConnection);
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     command.Parameters.Add("@theDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
     sqlConnection.Open();
     int result = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
     sqlConnection.Close();

     if (result == 1)
     return true;//or any message 
     else
     return false;    
  }
catch (SqlException ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: upvoted, your answer fixes a blatant error that I have forgotten to address in my answer.